# Need to pull values from multiple check boxes into an array and store it as a variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a modal that I am using for a coding boot camp assignment -

I have 7 days of the week listed as well as weekend/weekday options.

I thought I could use the Jquery .each and CSS :checked to pull the values that I had assigned to each of these inputs but I seem to be doing something wrong as every time I try to console log the array I am pushing to - it returns an empty array.

This is my first post on StackOverflow and I am extremely new to coding, please be gentle :)

Apologies in advance for syntax and formatting. Like I said I am super new and have only been coding for about 1.5 months.

I tried giving all the checkboxes different ID's and pulling the values one by one into an array, I also tried giving them all the same name so I could use the CSS checked feature to pull them all at once using .each and this. Neither seemed to work

```
//below is the check box portion of the modal//

<div class="form-check form-check-inline">
        <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" name="daysOfWeek" value="Monday">
        <label for="Monday">Monday</label>
      </div>
      <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
        <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" name="daysOfWeek" value="Tuesday">
        <label for="Tuesday">Tuesday</label>
      </div>
      <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
            <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" name="daysOfWeek" value="Wednesday">
            <label for="Wednesday">Wednesday</label>
    </div>
    <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
            <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" name="daysOfWeek" value="Thursday">
            <label  for="Thursday">Thursday</label>
    </div>
    <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
            <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" name="daysOfWeek" value="Friday">
            <label  for="Friday">Friday</label>
    </div>
    <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
            <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" name="daysOfWeek" value="Saturday">
            <label  for="Saturday">Saturday</label>
    </div>
    <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
            <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" name="daysOfWeek" value="Sunday">
            <label for="Sunday">Sunday</label>
    </div>
    <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
      <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" name="daysOfWeek" value="Weekday">
      <label for="Weekday">Weekday</label>
    </div>
    <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
    <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" name="daysOfWeek" value="Weekend">
    <label  for="Weekend">Weekend</label>
    </div>


// here is where I try to call the values of which boxes are checked back//

$("#submitButton").on("click", function () {
    event.preventDefault();
            var  daysOfWeek1 = [];
                  $.each($("input[name='dayOfWeek']:checked"), function(){
                    daysOfWeek1.push($(this).val());
                  });

      console.log(daysOfWeek1)

    });
```

I would like to get an array back containing the values (set of strings) that I entered for each check box options and be able to store it in a variable and console.log it as well.

Right now I am only getting an empty array

Comment: have you tried `console.log(daysOfWeek1)`  inside `$.each` loop ?

Comment: You are so very close! Like many of our greatest headaches in code, it all comes down to a single, little typo ;)

Answer (score 0):

It's even simpler - just use `map`, then convert it to an array (to remove excess properties) using spread syntax:

```js
$("#submitButton").on("click", function() {
  event.preventDefault();
  var daysOfWeek1 = [...$("input[name='daysOfWeek']:checked").map((i, el) => $(el).val())];
  console.log(daysOfWeek1)
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
<div class="form-check form-check-inline">
  <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" name="daysOfWeek" value="Monday">
  <label for="Monday">Monday</label>
</div>
<div class="form-check form-check-inline">
  <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" name="daysOfWeek" value="Tuesday">
  <label for="Tuesday">Tuesday</label>
</div>
<div class="form-check form-check-inline">
  <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" name="daysOfWeek" value="Wednesday">
  <label for="Wednesday">Wednesday</label>
</div>
<div class="form-check form-check-inline">
  <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" name="daysOfWeek" value="Thursday">
  <label for="Thursday">Thursday</label>
</div>
<div class="form-check form-check-inline">
  <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" name="daysOfWeek" value="Friday">
  <label for="Friday">Friday</label>
</div>
<div class="form-check form-check-inline">
  <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" name="daysOfWeek" value="Saturday">
  <label for="Saturday">Saturday</label>
</div>
<div class="form-check form-check-inline">
  <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" name="daysOfWeek" value="Sunday">
  <label for="Sunday">Sunday</label>
</div>
<div class="form-check form-check-inline">
  <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" name="daysOfWeek" value="Weekday">
  <label for="Weekday">Weekday</label>
</div>
<div class="form-check form-check-inline">
  <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" name="daysOfWeek" value="Weekend">
  <label for="Weekend">Weekend</label>
  <button id="submitButton">Submit</button>
</div>
```

Comment: No problem @WillCoe, always glad to help.

Answer (score 0):

ooops. It totally works - I just used dayOfWeek below and daysOfWeek above...

> .>

Sorry to bother you